# Golang: "redeclared in this block" errors with no changes all of a sudden

Tags: go

**Using go 1.14.2**

This is an existing GO project that's around compressing log files, and through one of the packages it's getting this /net dependency indirectly, and it project had been getting built fine with 1.14.2 until a few months back, and now when we rebuild it, it throws these "redeclared in this block" errors.

**Importantly**, as this had been building fine until a few months back, and all of a sudden, now it doesn't get built, pointing to a dependency issue, possibly? I think without a go.mod file, this downloads the latest, causing these issues?

Errors we get

```
build/src/golang.org/x/net/context/pre_go17.go:48:2: todo redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at build/src/golang.org/x/net/context/go17.go:15:2
```

Looked at the other posts around this error wherein we've advised we need to undo the previous versions of Go, and install it afresh. However, we're building this **inside a docker container on a gitlab runner**, not sure why we get these errors here. For now, these are for a package "golang.org/x/net/context" - I looked at the code downloaded for this, and it does contain declaration in two files - go17 & pre_go17.
Saw this - https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/master:context/

I'm not sure why do we have two here? looking at the names here, I think only one is meant to be in use, but how? based on an env variable or what?

Although not useful, I tried redoing the version again inside the container, just to give it a try

```
  script:
    - ls -lrt /usr/local/go
    - rm -rf /usr/local/go
    - "curl -fSL https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.14.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz -o go.tgz"
    - tar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz
    - rm go.tgz
```

I'm new to GO, tried thinking if /x/net version has been upgraded to be incompatible somehow with go1.14.2, did see https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net@v0.1.0/context?tab=versions - but not sure which one is downloaded here for my package as the package I'm building does not have a go.mod file, doesn't specify the versions to be downloaded. It's an old one. I can upgrade it but then will need to do other things as well - go.mod etc. I will do this in the long run, but for now, I just need to make this work

Comment: Go 1.14 is years outdated, use the actual one (only).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure why do we have two here? looking at the names here, I think only one is meant to be in use, but how? based on an env variable or what?

The files themselves contain ["build constraints"](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) — e.g.

```
//go:build !go1.7
```

— that newer versions of the Go toolchain understand. These constraints tell Go to ignore a given source file unless it meets certain conditions, and in the case of this module, they (taken together) ensure that only one of the seemingly conflicting files is actually used.

So, you can solve your problem by using the current Go compiler, which understands these constraints. If you're not ready yet to truly update to the latest Go, that should be fine: you can use the latest compiler, but specify the desired old Go version in [a `go` directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-work-file-go) in your go.mod file.

Comment: thanks, I tried this given go1.14 supports tags - "go build -tags go1.7,go1.9" to pick up only the ones with these tags from this package, however, I still get the same errors, go isn't reading those properly? I'm not sure "go help build" does say tags are supported.

Comment: "Go versions 1.16 and earlier used a different syntax for build constraints, with a '// +build' prefix." [[link](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints)] So go1.14 supports tags in theory, but it doesn't support the syntax that this library is using.

Comment: @karansardana, what ruakh said. You have to make sure that you're using golang.org/x/net/context at v0.17.0. Newer version include only the modern build constraints. Or stop using x/net/context. It is obsolete since 2016! Updating should be as simple as replacing "golang.org/x/net/context" with "context" in all .go files.

Comment: thanks @Peter - was simple in the end, I just had to upgrade it to "context" from the std library. This is the first time I'm working with Go, thanks for your help. Things will get clearer as I move along.